# Creating SharePoint site collection using Admin.asmx web service

Tags: sharepoint, service, web, sitecollection

I am creating a site collection by calling a built-in SharePoint web service.

```
http://Server_Name/_vti_adm/admin.asmx
```

This web service has a method called `CreateSite` which allows users to create a site collection. Pretty straight forward ([method documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/administration.admin.createsite%28v=office.12%29.aspx)).

It creates a site with a URL such as:

```
http://Server_Name/sites/SiteCollection_Name
```

I would like to create a site collection where the Name of the Site comes first, such as:

```
http://SiteCollection_Name/Server_Name
```

I remember there is a property called **UseHostHeaderAsSiteName**

I can't see an option to use this property with `CreateSite` method.  How do we use this property or any method to create a site that will give the URL such as:

```
http://SiteCollection_Name/Server_Name
```

Answer (score 0):

What you describe - `http://SiteCollection_Name/Server_Name` - is not possible by the SP API. The URL format is `protocol://server:port/path`. The site collection can occur only in the `path`.

If you need different hostnames - the `server` part -  you'd have to register them in the DNS mapped to your SP server IP address and then set up alternative access URLs in your SP web application so that they are accepted by SP. (SP is picky if you do not use the same hostname in the URL which it was installed with...)